# Hadoop - namenode will not start

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, server, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to run hadoop on ubuntu server. After i start all services and typ JPS I get

```
hduser@HDFS1:/usr/local/hadoop/etc/hadoop$ jps
5938 DataNode
6133 SecondaryNameNode
6287 ResourceManager
6431 NodeManager
6751 Jps
```

I believe I should NameNode along with the secondary namne node.

The hdfs-site.xml is

```
<configuration>
<property>
<name>dfs.replication</name>
<value>1</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
<property>
<name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
<value>file:/usr/local/hadoop_tmp/hdfs/datanode</value>
</property>
</configuration>
```

I have also tried the configuration from another question similar to this with no luck.

Comment: check above core-site.xml parameters, you posted hdfs-site.xml parameters. and can you post namenode logs..?

Comment: That was a typo. Above is the hdfs-site.xml. I will post the namenode logs and the core-site parameters as soon as I can.

Comment: What's the output of `hdfs dfsadmin -report`? The output of `hdfs fsck /`? What about the namenode logs? Have you tried `hdfs namenode -recover`?

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed the issue. For some reason the it did not format right the first two times i tried it. When I executed namenode -recover I got an error message saying it had not been formatted. Thanks for the help